# emplace_back is faster than allocate once + move in c++11?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I have two fuctions:

f2 - first allocate memory , then move data.

f - deallocate + move = emplace_back.

I am trying to understand what is faster and better to use in terms of performance and code quality?

```
void f2(const std::vector<std::string>& users) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> userOccurancies(users.size());

    auto userOcIt = userOccurancies.begin();
    for (const auto & user : users) {
        userOcIt->first = std::move(user);
        userOcIt->second = 0;
        userOcIt++;
    }
}

void f(const std::vector<std::string>& users) {
    std::vector < std::pair<std::string, std::size_t>> userCount;
    userCount.reserve(users.size());

    for (auto& user : users) {
        userCount.emplace_back(user, 0);
    }
}
```

As for performance I tried to check it with MS VS2019 profiler but it always gives me different results if a swap calls of these funcions with each other: `f2(users);f(users);` and `f(users);f2(users);` gives different call tree.

Can you help me?

What is faster and better to use in terms of performance and code quality?

I use only c++11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893787/emplace-back-is-faster-than-allocate-once-move-in-c11/61894931#61894931 Main discussion and an answer is here

Comment: Welcome to Code Review Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, such questions are not allowed. This website is people who want a critique of their working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm reviewing this because I believe that both `f` and `f2` actually work; I think the discussion of "different call tree" is just talking about difficulty in profiling them meaningfully.]

From a code quality viewpoint, I think `f` is a clear win. `emplace_back` precisely describes what we want to accomplish here. `f2` spends a great deal more effort on the mechanics of filling the vector with the desired data.

However, I can't say I'm particularly excited about either one. First of all, I'm...less than excited about using `std::pair`. In most cases, I'd rather define a class with meaningful names for the members. In this case, it at least *looks* like you're counting the number of times each user name occurs (or something on that order). That being the case, I'd probably define a structure something along this line:

```
struct UserCount { 
    std::string userName;
    int count { 0 };
    UserCount(std::string const &s) : userName(s) {}
};
```

With that in place, we can construct our vector directly from the source:

```
std::vector<UserCount> userOccurancies(users.begin(), users.end());
```

This should normally be at least as fast as either `f` or `f2`, and may be faster than either (though honestly, I wouldn't expect a huge speed gain from it).

That does lead to two other possibilities though.

1. If we can count on `users` remaining valid for the entire time that `userOccurancies` will exist, we can have `UserCount` store just a reference to the user name rather than storing a copy of it.
2. Conversely, if we know that `users` will only be used to initialize `userOccurancies`, we can move the strings rather than copying them. Either of these is likely to be faster than copying the strings (if circumstances allow them, of course).

A little here may also depend on what we're trying to optimize though. Storing references to the original strings may hurt cache locality a bit, so if we're *using* `userOccurancies` a lot, it may be faster overall to copy the strings rather than just storing references to them. This becomes especially true with short strings (for some definition of 'short') and a `std::string` that implements the short string optimization (which most modern implementations do).